# How do I change the outline color (stroke) of my shape after drawing it?

Tags: colors, processing, stroke

I'm coding in Processing for the first time (previously familiar with Java) and I'm trying to make a grid of triangles where when I click one, it changes the fill and stroke to a different color. The fill is changing but the stroke remains the default color. Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 600); // size of canvas
  triangles = new ArrayList<TriangleClass>();  // Create an empty ArrayList

  int L = 50; // length of triangle side
  double halfStep = L * Math.sqrt(3);

  // all the code about making the grid
} 

void draw() {
  background(0);
  TriangleClass myCurrentTriangle;

  for (int i = 0; i < triangles.size(); i++) {
    // get object from ArrayList
    myCurrentTriangle = triangles.get(i);
    myCurrentTriangle.display();
  } 
} 

void mouseClicked () {
  TriangleClass myCurrentTriangle ;
  for (int i=0; i < triangles.size(); i++) {
    // get object from ArrayList
    myCurrentTriangle = triangles.get(i);
    myCurrentTriangle.mouseOver();
  }
}

class TriangleClass {
  double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;    // points
  color fill; // fill color
  color stroke; // stroke color
  float mouseSensorX, mouseSensorY;// check point for dist to mouse

  // constructor
  TriangleClass(
    //  ...
    stroke = color(174, 208, 234);
    fill = color(249, 249, 249);
    mouseSensorX = (float) (x1+x2+x3 )/ 3;
    mouseSensorY = (float) (y1+y2+y3 )/ 3;
  }  

  void mouseOver() {
    if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, mouseSensorX, mouseSensorY) < 17) {
      if (fill == color(249, 249, 249)) {
        stroke = color(251, 84, 84);
        fill = color(251,84,84);
      // ... repeated for other colors
    }
  } 

  void display() {
    // show triangle
    stroke(stroke);
    fill(fill);
    triangle((float) x1, (float) y1, (float) x2, (float) y2, (float) x3, (float) y3);
  } 
} 
// =====================================================================
```

Comment: Could you provide the entire code?

Comment: @MorganS42 done!

Comment: actually it appears that there are still some missing pieces of code making it difficult to see what's going wrong, could you maybe send the entire code?

Comment: the stuff that's missing is just about drawing out the grid - i couldn't add it because it said there was too much code lmao @Morgan

Comment: Ok, that's fair. But could I get the exact error message you're receiving? Or is there no error message and it's just not changing?

Comment: @Morgan when I click to change the color of each shape in the grid, it appears to not always be changing the outline. So if I have two neighboring triangles that I've changed to red, they still have this faint blue outline between them from when I originally drew the unfilled grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is the stroke weight. All you need to do it have this line of code at the end of your setup function:

```
strokeWeight(3);
```

The larger the number, the larger the outline.

Comment: No problem, could you please mark the answer as correct since it worked?

Comment: @Richard Please tick the checkmark near the voting buttons if this answer helped you out. It both gives reputation to the member which wrote it and signal other people looking for an answer that this thread had a solution.

Comment: @Morgan gotcha!